I try using pip install anonympy for my data privacy project but got error
However I then got this error
Collecting anonympy
  Using cached anonympy-0.3.7.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in anonympy setup command: 'python_requires' must be a string containing valid version specifiers; Invalid specifier: '>=3.6*'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Anyone manage to explain this since I cant find similar solution

https://github.com/ArtLabss/open-data-anonymizer/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%27python_requires%27+must+be+a+string+containing+valid+version+specifiers%3B+Invalid+specifier%3A+%27%3E%3D3.6*%27
